# Creating masks for specific nibbles

Tags: 64-bit, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

How can I - in an as efficient manner as possible - create a mask for all nibbles in an unsigned 64-bit integer that match a certain value?

For example, suppose I have a 64-bit unsigned integer:

```
0000 0100 0011 0011 0011 0011 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0001 0001 0001 0001
```

And say I only want to allow the nibbles that have values of 0010.
How can I find those nibbles and create the mask for them.
In this contrived example I know of course nibbles 5:10 are 0010, and so the corresponding mask to create is:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

But I'd like to create such masks for any 64-bit unsigned integer and any nibble value. I might be interested in `0100`, `0010`, or `1000` nibbles for example.

Comment: This is an interesting question in a puzzle-solving sense, but I wonder whether it may be an XY-problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example as follows (just a composition of well known tricks)

1. XOR with the desired values, making a nibble 0 *iff* it has the right value
2. Compute the horizontal-OR for all nibbles
3. Remove junk bits
4. Widen the results to fit whole nibbles
5. The mask ends up inverted, to invert it back

So, not tested:

```
x ^= test_value
// now h-OR nibbles
x |= x >> 1
x |= x >> 2
// remove junk
x &= 0x1111111111111111
// widen
x *= 15
// invert
x = ~x
```

Comment: That's amazing thank you! I came up with a solution 10 minutes before checking back at the question, I've included it for completeness, but it's not as neat as your solution! I accept yours as the answer.

Comment: Does the step "Computing the horizontal-OR for all nibbles" ensure that for any given test_value, each non-zero nibble follows the form XXX1? X can either be 1/0.

Comment: @SebNag the XOR will leave a nibble in the 0000 state only if it matches the test value, otherwise there will be a 1 in it somewhere. The horizontal OR will put that 1 into the least significant bit of the nibble, no matter where it came from (and also potentially other locations, those are removed with the AND)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version I managed to come up with after hours of trial and error, but is norwhere near as neat as harold's version. I post it here just for completeness:
I wrote it out in the julia language.

```
@inline function mask_nibbles(x::UInt64, value::UInt64)
    x = ~(x $ value)
    x = (x & 0x1111111111111111) &
    ((x >> 1) & 0x1111111111111111) &
    ((x >> 2) & 0x1111111111111111) &
    ((x >> 3) & 0x1111111111111111)
    return x | (x << 1) | (x << 2) | (x << 3)
end
```